# Updating SQL tables after a SELECT statement with joins

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to issue an update to specific rows of a mysql query.  Although some of the rows are not updating correctly.  I am assuming this is because the query that I am trying to update is being derived from a bunch of join.

```
SELECT
        vtiger_users.user_name,
        vtiger_troubletickets.*,
        vtiger_crmentity.*  
    FROM
        vtiger_troubletickets
    LEFT JOIN(
        vtiger_crmentity,
        vtiger_users
    )ON(
        vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_troubletickets.ticketid AND
        vtiger_crmentity.smownerid = vtiger_users.id
    )WHERE
        vtiger_troubletickets.status != "Closed"
    UPDATE vtiger_troubletickets 
LEFT JOIN(vtiger_crmentity, vtiger_users
)ON
(vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_troubletickets.ticketid AND vtiger_crmentity.smownerid = vtiger_users.id) SET smownerid = '6'
WHERE ticket_no='TT63'
```

Now....that query works fine in regards to returning the data I want.  When I try to update the data this query returns with this statement:

```
UPDATE vtiger_troubletickets t 
LEFT JOIN (vtiger_crmentity, vtiger_users) 
       ON (vtiger_crmentity.crmid = t.ticketid 
       AND vtiger_crmentity.smownerid = vtiger_users.id) 
SET smownerid='1' AND t.status='Abandon' 
WHERE t.ticket_no='TT63'
```

It says it has worked, but does not update the smownerid or the status of the ticket aside from assigning the values as null.  Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AND` here:

```
SET smownerid='1' AND t.status='Abandon'
```

should be a comma:

```
SET smownerid='1', t.status='Abandon'
```

See the [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) in the MySQL manual.

> ```
> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
> SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
> [WHERE where_condition]        ^
>                                ^ comma
> ```

Comment: Perfect, see you look at things to long and you realize it was that easy.  Cheers